# how to reduce RestFull Api response size?

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I have a web site witch using **Angularjs** to connect to An api written in **php** to get data and perform action and ths api send a json result. in checking site performance I found that my server response is very lass than downloading response from the web!!!
how can I change json property name by shorter aliases? for example:

```
 {
     "name": "test", 
     "family": "testi" 
 }
```

must be converted to:

```
 {
     "n": "test", 
     "f": "testi"
 }
```

[image: this is picture of my browser network monitor for this request:]

indeed in 2nd form of response content length is much shorter if my response contain an array of object.

is there any technology for client and server side for this issue? or is there any other solution?

Comment: Unless you have control over both endpoints of the API there's no way to reduce the size of the responses (apart from compressing the connection, which would just shift the load to the cpu instead of the network). If you do have control then there shouldn't be a problem just rewriting your api? There's no way this can simply be automated "behind  the scenes".

Comment: Plus: Nowadays resources such as CPU / RAM / bandwidth are abundant, it's much more preferable to write a clean api than saving up some bytes on bandwidth. (Your example differs in 8 bytes, I know it's only to show... but even if it were 800 bytes, even if you have a million requests on that resource a day it'd just sum up to ~770mb... which, at that point would probably be considered trivial)

Comment: my problem is "time". my site spend 11s to download this response form the web and user must wait until this operation done. i want to reduce this time for getting best user experience.

Comment: and i want to know is there any technology or best practice for achieving this goal?

Comment: That 11s is probably not spend transfering the data from the server to the client. Have you tried using the network profiler of your browser to see how long it's waiting for data?

Comment: i add result of network profiler to my quetion

Comment: What is the size of that download? And bandwidth limit of your and your hosts connection? Downloading 11s would have to be ~550mb on my bandwidth, even with ~50mbit that'd still be ~70mb... if that's the case just renaming some fields would probably hardly yield sufficient reduction.

Comment: my host bandwidth is gigabit. my client bandwidth is slow and i want to help slow users to have best response witch is possible

Comment: Depending on your webserver and your control over it's config files you could try enabling compression (for example using mod_gzip or mod_deflate for apache).

Comment: ok. but is there any other solution ??

Comment: As I said at the beginning: Not if you don't have access to both endpoints of the API and can rename / shorten keys, remove unneeded characters (line breaks, whitespace etc). You have X amount of "raw data" to transfer using Y speed, that takes - by definition - `X / Y` seconds. Since you can't change your clients bandwidth you can just try to minimize your download size X. If you don't have access to the api server at all then that's simply not an option and you're stuck with what you have.

Comment: How big is this response? You're trying to optimize the size of response without even determining it's the size that's the problem. Changing a few key names and shortening them won't make your site work much better for users with slow connection.

Comment: Hello @Navid_pdp11 did you find an optimal solution for reducing the size of the 
 API response?

Answer (score 1):

We can compress our response by GZIP. also there is some high-performance serialization protocol like Protobuff or Thrift those are fast and secure but I think they are server to server solutions and using them in front-end area can not be a very efficient solution. also, We can create some mapping that can map our minimized property names in back-end DTOs to our front-end data models.

They are the solutions founded in my explorations and experiences. Any new suggestions are welcomed;